# Advertised Window Size

Tags: packet-analysis, tcpdump

I have one sender and one receiver node, connected through one switch. I am collecting advertised window size from both tcpdump and kernel. I am running tcp dump on the receiver side, to watch for window size on ACK packets, and also I've added some code in "tcp_input.c" file to printk the snd_wnd value. I believe these two values should be the same. I put data on two graphs, and the observed values on both graphs are completely different. I don't know why this is happening and I'm trying to find an answer for it. Here you can see these two graphs.

TCPDUMP result:
[image: TCPDUMP Result]

KERNEL result:

[image: Kernel Result]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Send window is different than the Receive window.  In an ACKnowledgement packet (segment), the sender of the ACK is advertising its **Receive window**.  At no time in a TCP communication are either party sharing with each other their **Send window**.

The SND_window is a running count of data the sender is meaning to send, as well as data that is sent that has not yet been acknowledged.  Whereas the RCV_window is a running count of data the receiver is willing to accept that is within the advertised window size.

Take a look at these two pictures from the TCP/IP Guide:
[image: SND Window]
[image: RCV Window]

You can (should) read the full articles on the [Send](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPSlidingWindowDataTransferandAcknowledgementMech-2.htm) and [Receive](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPSlidingWindowDataTransferandAcknowledgementMech-3.htm) windows at the [TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks much eddie for the valuable information. I totally got what did you mean by receive and send window. The point is, I'm trying to capture the size of the receive window of the client on both "TCP dump" and the sender kernel. When the sender receives the acknowledgement, then it would parse the window size that is advertised. Then I see inconsistency between what tcpdump see and what kernel see. They don't report the same receive window of the receiver.